# Explicación del funcionamiento de parseInt en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

¿Qué es el *parseInt* y para qué sirve en programación? Consulté esta página: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
 y no me queda  claro ya que lo aplico  en la consola.

Answer (score 18):

`parseInt()` es una función de alto nivel que sirve para **parsear** una cadena e *intentar* obtener un valor numérico a partir de esta.

Por intentar me refiero lo sgte:

Una cadena que evidentemente es un número, es fácilmente obtenible como `number`. Ejemplo:

```js
var s = "1234";
var n = parseInt(s);
console.log(n); // 1234
```

Por supuesto también acepta negativos

```js
var s = "-1234";
var n = parseInt(s);
console.log(n); // -1234
```

Sin embargo una cadena que no represente a un número como la sgte

```js
    var s = "5678EstoYaNoEsNumero";
    var n = parseInt(s);
    console.log(n); // 5678
```

Igualmente obtiene un valor válido, que corresponde al número resultante de convertir a number los dígitos hasta donde se pudo.

Este comportamiento resulta ideal por ejemplo en campos de texto cuando pueden haber espacios en blanco antes o después ejemplo:

```js
    var s = "  4321  ";
    var n = parseInt(s);
    console.log(n); // 4321
```

Cuando el parseo ya no puede obtener ningún número, este se detiene así hayan más dígitos posteriormente por lo que en este caso el parseo devolverá `NaN` lo que significa que no pudo obtener un valor válido. Ejemplo:

```js
        var s = "   abc8765  ";
        var n = parseInt(s);
        console.log(n); // NaN
```

Pero no solo permite parsear cadenas en base 10 por ejemplo lo sgte también es válido en base hexadecimal

```js
var sHexa = "0xDEAD";
var nHexa = parseInt(sHexa);
console.log(nHexa); // 57005
```

Finalmente si se desea parsear una cadena en otra base se puede indicar con el segundo argumento de la función, por ejemplo para parsear una cadena binaria:

```js
var sBin = "10101010";
var nBin = parseInt(sBin, 2);
console.log(nBin); // 170
```

Comment: Muy buena explicación, sería bueno también añadir un ejemplo de para qué puede ser útil. Por ejemplo, si se quieren sumar dos numeros obtenidos de dos `input` y ponerlos en un tercero.

Answer (score 6):

> ¿Qué es el parseInt y para qué sirve en programación?

parseInt lo que hace es analizar una cadena de texto y retornar el valor numérico.

Cuando nosotros escribimos en el teclado algún número (ej `123`), el teclado envía un conjunto de carácteres codificados por cada tecla enviada (comúnmente en *ascii*), así 
la cadena de carácteres `1 2 3` es representado internamente como `0x31 0x32 0x33`. Por otro lado `123` como número debe representarse internamente como `0x7B`
Entonces `parseInt` transforma los bytes `0x31 0x32 0x33` en `0x7B`

```js
function analizarEntero(cadena)
{
 var r = 0
 for(var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++)
   {
    var c = cadena.charCodeAt(i) - 0x30
    if(c < 0 || c > 9)
     throw new Error("Se esperan sólo dígitos")
    r = r * 10 + c
   }
 return r
}

console.log(analizarEntero('1230'))
```

El anterior código muestra como convertir una cadena a un entero, primero se  convierte el *ascii* a un dígito válido (0-9), se desplaza a la izquierda el acumulador (en nuestro sistema esto se hace multiplicando por 10) finalmente se suma el dígito, repetir hasta que no queden caracteres.

`Number.parseInt(string, radix)` hace algo parecido, pero él acepta más sistemas de númeración con sus respectivos símbolos

```js
console.log(Number.parseInt('F', 16)) // 15 en hex
console.log(Number.parseInt('15', 10)) // 15 en decimal
console.log(Number.parseInt('17', 8)) // 15 en octal
console.log(Number.parseInt('1111', 2)) // 15 en binario
```

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz  Tu enlace hace distinción entre el constructor Number, no el método estático Number.parseInt, mi respuesta no es errada basta hacer `parseInt === Number.parseInt` para ver que ambas funciones son las mismas, se recomienda siempre usar Number.parseInt.

Answer (score 4):

`parseInt` convierte un tipo de dato `String` a `Integer`:

```js
var numeroString = "1";
var numero = 1;

console.log(numeroString + numero); // Deberia de ser 2 pero nos retorna 11 porque para los tipos de datos String, el simbolo + es concatenacion, no suma.

var numero2 = parseInt(numeroString);// convertido el valor de numeroString a Integer para poder sumarlo
console.log(numero2 + numero); // ahora si nos da la suma de ambos numeros
```

Answer (score 4):

La [especificación Ecma Script explica en el apartado 18.2.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-parseint-string-radix), qué es `parseInt` y cómo funciona. Cuando se invoca `parseInt` se ejecutan 16 pasos explicados en el enlace indicado más arriba:

### 18.2.5 `parseInt (string, radix)`

La función `parseInt` produce un valor entero dictado por la interpretación del contenido del argumento `string` de acuerdo con la raíz (`radix`) especificada. Se ignora el espacio en blanco principal en la cadena. Si `radix` es indefinido o 0, se supone que es 10 excepto cuando el número comienza con los pares de unidades de código `0x` o `0X`, en cuyo caso se supone una base de 16. Si `radix` es 16, el número también puede comenzar opcionalmente con los pares de unidades de código `0x` o `0X`.

La función `parseInt` es el objeto intrínseco *%parseInt%*. Cuando se llama a la función `parseInt`, se realizan los pasos siguientes:

1. ¿Podría ser *inputString*? [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-tostring) (string).
2. Sea *S* una subcadena de *inputString* recién creada que consiste en la primera unidad de código que no es un [StrWhiteSpaceChar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-StrWhiteSpaceChar) y todas las unidades de código que siguen a esa unidad de código. (En otras palabras, elimine el espacio en blanco principal.) Si *inputString* no contiene ninguna unidad de código, S será una cadena vacía.
3. Deje que el *signo* sea 1.
4. Si *S* no está vacío y la primera unidad de código de *S* es 0x002D (HYPHEN-MINUS), deje que el signo sea -1.
5. Si *S* no está vacío y la primera unidad de código de *S* es 0x002B (PLUS SIGN) o 0x002D (HYPHEN-MINUS), quite la primera unidad de código de *S*.
6. ¿Puede ser *R*? [ToInt32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-toint32) (radix).
7. Deje que *stripPrefix* sea **verdadero**.
8. Si *R* ≠ 0, entonces:

   a) Si *R* <2 o *R*> 36, devuelve **NaN**.

   b) Si *R* ≠ 16, deje que *stripPrefix* sea **false**.
9. Else *R* = 0,

   a) sea R 10.
10. Si *stripPrefix* es **true**, entonces

    a) Si la longitud de *S* es al menos 2 y las dos primeras unidades de código de *S* son "0x" o "0X", quite las dos primeras unidades de código de S y deje que *R* sea 16.
11. Si *S* contiene una unidad de código que no es un dígito radix-*R*, sea *Z* la subcadena de *S* que consiste en todas las unidades de código antes de la primera unidad de código; en caso contrario, sea *Z* = *S*.
12. Si *Z* está vacío, devuelva **NaN**.
13. Sea *mathInt* el valor entero matemático representado por *Z* en la notación radix-*R*, usando las letras **A-Z** y **a-z** para los dígitos con valores de 10 a 35. (Sin embargo, si *R* es 10 y *Z* contiene más de 20 dígitos significativos, después de 20 puede ser reemplazado por un dígito 0, a opción de la implementación, y si *R* no es 2, 4, 8, 10, 16 o 32, entonces mathInt puede ser una aproximación dependiente de la implementación al entero matemático Valor que se representa por *Z* en la notación radix-*R*).
14. Si *mathInt* = 0, entonces
     a) Si *sing* = -1, devuelve **-0**.
     b) Devuelve **+0**.
15. Sea *number* el valor numérico para *mathInt*.
16. Devuelve *sign* × *number*.

---

NOTA

> ParseInt puede interpretar sólo una porción principal de cadena como
>   un valor entero; ignora cualquier unidad de código que no pueda ser
>   interpretada como parte de la notación de un número entero, y no se
>   indica que tales unidades de código fueron ignoradas.

Comment: La verdad no os entiendo, ésta respuesta es la mejor de todas y no tiene votos, mientras que otras son muy amplias, ambigüas no responden del todo a la pregunta, y tienen varios puntos, consistencia por favor.

Comment: En parte puede deberse a que esta respuesta es reciente @EduenSarceño