# ¿Por qué al cumplirse la condición del if se muestra NaN en el resultado?

Tags: javascript

En este código deseo aplicar un descuento cuando el usuario elija 10 o más noches de alojamiento, pero no encuentro el error de por qué, aún parseando en el prompt, cuando se cumple la condición en el `if` como resultado sigue arrojando `NaN`...

```js
let estadia = parseInt(prompt('ingrese cantidad de noches'))

let descuentoEstadiaXL = 200



const descuento = (a, b) => a - b

const costoEstadia = x => x * 1000



let precioFinal = descuento(costoEstadia, descuentoEstadiaXL)

const precioEstadia = costoEstadia(estadia)



if (estadia >= 10) {

    alert(precioFinal)

    descuento(costoEstadia, descuentoEstadiaXL)

    console.log(precioFinal)

}


alert('EL precio total de la estadia es ' + precioEstadia)

console.log('EL precio total de la estadia es ' + precioEstadia)
```

Comment: Esto es lo que te hace falta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/92279/6798

Comment: Entiendo el proceso del parseo @Alfabravo pero lo que no entiendo es que si parseo justo al principio de solicitar el dato en el prompt, ¿por qué sigue dando NaN?

Comment: Estás pasando como argumento de `descuento` una función y no el resultado de la misma. Esta linea: `let precioFinal = descuento(costoEstadia, descuentoEstadiaXL);` debería ser: `let precioFinal = descuento(costoEstadia(estadia), descuentoEstadiaXL);`. Además, por buenas prácticas, acostumbra a poner el `;` al final de cada sentencia. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Estás pasando como argumento de `descuento` una función y no el resultado de la misma. En esta linea:

```js
let precioFinal = descuento(costoEstadia, descuentoEstadiaXL);
```

El primer argumento que pasas es una función. Por lo tanto, al realizar la operación de resta de una función con un entero el rsultado es `NaN`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo que debes hacer es pasar el resultado de la función `costoEstadía`. Tal vez lo que enreda es la sintaxis de flecha que usas para la declaración de la función:

```js
const costoEstadia = x => x * 1000;
```

Esto es lo mismo que:

```js
const costoEstadia = x => {
  return x * 1000;
}
```

E incluso puedes declarar tu función así también:

```js
const costoEstadia = function(x) {
  return x * 1000;
}
```

O directamente:

```js
function costoEstadia(x) {
  return x * 1000;
}
```

El asunto es que luego usas:

```js
let precioFinal = descuento(costoEstadia, descuentoEstadiaXL);
```

Por lo cual, sabiendo la firma de la función descuento, se observa que el argumento `a` es la función `precioFinal` que no es lo mismo que el resultado de `precioFinal(estadia)`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const descuento = (a,b) => {
  console.log(typeof a);
  console.log(typeof b);
  console.log("");
}

const costoEstadia = x => x * 1000;

descuento(costoEstadia, 200);
// function
// number

descuento(costoEstadia(1000), 200);
// number
// number
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

El código corregido podría verse:

```js
let estadia = parseInt(prompt('ingrese cantidad de noches'));

let descuentoEstadiaXL = 200;

const descuento = (a, b) => a - b;

const costoEstadia = x => x * 1000;

let precioFinal = descuento(costoEstadia(estadia), descuentoEstadiaXL);

const precioEstadia = costoEstadia(estadia);

if (estadia >= 10) {
    alert(precioFinal);
    descuento(costoEstadia(estadia), descuentoEstadiaXL);
    console.log(precioFinal);
}

alert('EL precio total de la estadia es ' + precioEstadia);

console.log('EL precio total de la estadia es ' + precioEstadia);
```

Además, como buena práctica, acostumbra a colocar el `;` al final de cada sentencia.